# How to register callback with PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine/PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx?

Tags: windows, callback, kernel, driver

I'm trying to learn how to code windows drivers, unfortunately information is scarce, and sometimes i find it difficult to get the full picture from reading the `MSDN` pages.

In saying that, a couple of weeks ago i found some fairly simple code example that registered a callback with one of the above mentioned functions, and would print some info to the debug console when a process was created, i modified it slightly to just print out the name of the executable and the **PID**. I planned to save it for later reference, but at some point i deleted the code by mistake, and now when i tried to implement the same thing again i can't get it to work, every time i try load the driver i just get an `ACCESS DENIED` error.

Here's the `NotifyRoutine`

```
VOID PsCreateProcessNotifyEx_CB(IN PEPROCESS Process, IN HANDLE ProcessId, IN PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo)
{
    if(CreateInfo)
        DbgPrint("PID = %d\r\n", ProcessId);
}
```

I'm registering the callback in `DriverEntry` like this.

```
NTSTATUS NtStatus = PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(PsCreateProcessNotifyEx_CB, FALSE);
```

Then also removing in `DriverUnload` by setting the Remove parameter to `TRUE`

I wish i could find the original page where i got the code i was first referencing, but I've searched for hours and tried a few different things, i just can't get it to work now.

Someone point out what i'm missing please.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx documentation in the return value it says "The image that contains the callback routine pointer did not have IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY set in its image header." You need to add this option /INTEGRITYCHECK at the linker options in Visual Studio or you can just edit it in the sys file with a PE editor